# Solving for the square root by Newton's Method

Tags: matlab, loops, while-loop, iteration

[image]

---

yinitial = x

y_n approaches sqrt(x) as n->infinity

If theres an x input and tol input. Aslong as the |y^2-x| > tol is true compute the following equation of y=0.5*(y + x/y). How would I create a while loop  that will stop when |y^2-x| <= tol. So every time through the loop the y value changes. In order to get this answer--->

```
>>sqrtx = sqRoot(25,100)

sqrtx =
 7.4615
```

I wrote this so far:

```
function [sqrtx] = sqrRoot(x,tol)

n = 0;
x=0;%initialized variables

if x >=tol %skips all remaining code

   return

end

while x <=tol

    %code repeated during each loop

   x = x+1  %counting code

end
```

Comment: @Agawa001 - unless you knew that the method was solving for the square root by Newton's method before hand, you wouldn't know what to Google.

Comment: @rayryeng noone is here to solve fill-the-blanks exercises.

Comment: @Agawa001  Google appears to be robust to typos in search queries.  Maybe my time would be better spent studying their algorithm.

Comment: @JeffIrwin google is frenchy sometimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what you are supposed to do: Iterate using the equation for `y_{n+1}` over and over again.

In your code you should have a loop like

```
while abs(y^2 - x) > tol
   %// Calculate new y from the formula
end
```

Also note that `tol` should be small, as told in the other answer. The parameter `tol` actually tells you how inaccurate you want your solution to be. Normally you want more or less accurate solutions, so you set `tol` to a value near zero.

Comment: So if abs(y^2 -x) > tol then I would use the equation y = 0.5*(y+(x/y)). However what else do I need to do so i iterate this over and over?

Comment: Yes. There is nothing much more to do, actually. As you iterate over the formula, your `y` will get closer and closer to `sqrt(x)`. At least if your starting value is close enough to the exact solution, but this example is relatively harmless.

Answer (score 4):

That formula is using a modified version of Newton's method to determine the square root.  `y_n` is the previous iteration and `y_{n+1}` is the current iteration.  You just need to keep two variables for each, then when the criteria of tolerance is satisfied, you return the current iteration's output.  You also are incrementing the wrong value.  It should be `n`, not `x`.  You also aren't computing the tolerance properly... read the question more carefully.  You take the current iteration's output, square it, subtract with the desired value `x`, take the absolute value and see if the output is less than the tolerance.

Also, you need to make sure the tolerance is **small**.  Specifying the tolerance to be 100 will probably not allow the algorithm to iterate and give you the right answer.  It may also be useful to see how long it took to converge to the right answer.  As such, return `n` as a second output to your function:

```
function [sqrtx,n] = sqrRoot(x,tol) %// Change

%// Counts total number of iterations
n = 0;    

%// Initialize the previous and current value to the input
sqrtx = x;
sqrtx_prev = x;

%// Until the tolerance has been met...
while abs(sqrtx^2 - x) > tol

    %// Compute the next guess of the square root
    sqrtx = 0.5*(sqrtx_prev + (x/sqrtx_prev));

    %// Increment the counter
    n = n + 1;

    %// Set for next iteration
    sqrtx_prev = sqrtx;    
end
```

---

Now, when I run this code with `x=25` and `tol=1e-10`, I get this:

```
>> [sqrtx, n] = sqrRoot(25, 1e-10)

sqrtx =

     5

n =

     7
```

The square root of 25 is 5... at least that's what I remember from maths class back in the day.  It also took 7 iterations to converge.  Not bad.

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng, however I do want to get 7.4615 for my test case. How come you got a different answer?

Comment: @kal uh... the square root of 25 is NOT 7.4615.  What kind of test case is this?  I got a different answer because the square root of 25 is 5... if I recall from my childhood.

Comment: I think after it goes through the loop a couple of times it it becomes 7.4615. The Yn value changes each time through the loop

Comment: It shouldn't.  This algorithm finds the square root of a number.  The value should **decrease** at every iteration.  That is contrary to the definition of the square root. I'm sorry but your logic is flawed.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to solve this..

function [sqrtx] = sqRoot(x,tol)

sqrtx = x;%output = x

while  abs((sqrtx.^2) - x) > tol  %logic expression to test when it should

end

sqrtx = 0.5*((sqrtx) + (x/sqrtx)); %while condition prove true calculate

end

end

Comment: That code doesn't work.  Your `sqrtx` never updates because of the frivolous `end` statement inside the `while` loop, so this code will iterate forever. Sorry, -1.